# Unable to add other components to window after creating background using JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a java Application like a widget. Here is my code below

```
package newpackage;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();

    public MainFrame() {
        try {
            this.setUndecorated(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(new Dimension(360, 360));
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("imageexcel.gif"));
            imageLabel.setIcon(ii);
            add(imageLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.setVisible(true);

            Shape shape=new Ellipse2D.Float(0,0,360,360);
            AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(this, shape);
            AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);

            imageLabel.add(new JButton("START"));

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }

}
```

In the above code, I have done the following:

1. Created a Frame
2. Removed the Title Bar
3. Added the Background using JLabel
4. Changed the shape of window as circle according to the shape of image

Now I would like to add some components in to it and perform some action with them but no component is visible after adding.

I have tried adding to Frame as well as JLabel and no use from either.

[This is the image i used for background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4FEb.gif)
Please help me to proceed further....

Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JLabels use null layouts by default, and so your button will default to size 0,0. Try giving it a decent layout manager, even FlowLayout would likely work. Another solution is to keep the null layout and set the sizes and positions of added components, but this route is a dangerous route and one I don't recommend.

Actually a GridBagLayout works nice to center the components. Also add all components **before** calling `setVisible(true)`:

```
imageLabel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
this.setUndecorated(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(new Dimension(360, 360));
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("imageexcel.gif"));
imageLabel.setIcon(ii);
add(imageLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
imageLabel.add(new JButton("START"));
this.setVisible(true);
```

or better?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainPanelOvalFrame extends JPanel {
    private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "imageexcel.gif";
    private Window window;
    private Image img;

    public MainPanelOvalFrame(Window window, Image image) {
        this.window = window;
        this.img = image;

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(new JButton(new StartAction("Start", KeyEvent.VK_S)));

        int w = image.getWidth(this);
        int h = image.getHeight(this);
        Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, w, h);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(window, shape);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(window, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || img == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = img.getWidth(this);
        int h = img.getHeight(this);
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    private class StartAction extends AbstractAction {
        public StartAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            window.dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        URL imgUrl = MainPanelOvalFrame.class.getResource(RESOURCE_PATH);
        Image image = new ImageIcon(imgUrl).getImage();
        MainPanelOvalFrame mainPanel = new MainPanelOvalFrame(frame, image);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a Layout manager for imageLabel ,or use null as the Layout manager, then set the size and location of the JButton manually.

**to use Layout Manager**

```
    imageLabel.setIcon(ii);
    imageLabel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    imageLabel.add(new JButton("START"));

    //need to setLayout and add JButton before setVisible(true)   
    add(imageLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
```

**to use null layout**

```
    JButton j=new JButton("START");
    j.setSize(100,50);
    j.setLocation(imageLabel.getWidth()/2-j.getWidth()/2, imageLabel.getHeight()/2-j.getHeight()/2);
    //then add Button into imageLabel
    imageLabel.add(j);
```

Layout manager is usually recommended because it can fit different environment.